# How can you set a user property so that I can track analytics using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I'm looking to try and set a user property of 'staff' to specific users of my app so that I can exclude their data from the firebase analytics.

I have looked into firebase' documentation and from what I understand you can set user properties but to do so it would be by prompting the user to answer a question.

eg.

The following example shows adding a hypothetical favorite food property, which assigns the value in the string food to the active user:

`Analytics.setUserProperty(food, forName: "favorite_food")`

Is there a way to assign a user property based on their email address, for example if users email address includes '@company.com' then assign a user property of staff to them.

Also I am using React Native.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why it would prompt the user to answer questions when you set user property. Can you determine the user is staff or not programmatically? I guess based on your question, you can tell from the email address. Why don't you use regex or substring on the email address to determine?

Comment: @adbitx yeah I'm now going to use a regex and async storage to store the email address past the @ symbol. If this is the company name then it will not fire the function that sends the data to firebase. It's a bit of a workaround but it works for now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set a User Property in GA for Firebase you do not need to ask a user to fill a questionnaire.

User Properties are general concept that would let you filter the data on the Analytics report. This filter would provide more insight on the Events that Firebase Analytics logs automatically or the events that you log as custom events.

You can set up a user property that has the domain of the company with the parameter passed. Take a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/analytics/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/analytics/MainActivity.java) example. One this user property is set in the code, make sure to register it in the Firebase Console. Make sure the key of the user property in the code exactly match the key of the User Property created in Console. Once all is set, the backend will tie the code to the UI user property.

Finally, you can filter the reports based off this user property.

Comment: I'm now going to use a regex and async storage to store the email address past the @ symbol. If this is the company name then it will not fire the function that sends the data to firebase. It's a bit of a workaround but it works for now. Thanks for your help anyway and I will look into this more based on your answer to get a proper solution in place